# Create foreign key constraint on indirect data

Tags: postgresql, database-design, foreign-key, referential-integrity

I am trying to enforce relational integrity across some database design containing sensor data. The relevant parts of the database:

```
CREATE TABLE logger (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE sensor (
    logger_id INTEGER REFERENCES Logger(id),
    logger_sensor_id SMALLINT,
    PRIMARY KEY (logger_id, logger_sensor_id)   
);

CREATE TABLE measurement (
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    logger_id INTEGER REFERENCES logger(id)
)

CREATE TABLE sensor_measurement_data (
    measurement_id BIGINT REFERENCES measurement(id),
    logger_sensor_id REFERENCES sensor(logger_sensor_id) -- problem is here
)
```

Since `logger_sensor_id` is not unique in the `sensor` table, I can't create the foreign key in `sensor_measurement_data` and the above won't work. I want to create a foreign key on both the `logger_sensor_id` and the `logger_id` which is included in the `measurement` table.

Is it possible to create such an "indirect foreign key" constraint? I guess it's possible to ensure referential integrity through triggers and checks, but I'd like to know if it's possible with foreign keys - it looks it would be a lot less error-prone to me. If it's not possible, is there a technical reason for this?

I'm currently using postgresql, but I'd surely want to know if other systems would be able to implement the above.

Comment: I probably misunderstood you, but why not have `logger_id` field in `sensor_measurement_data` , and  normal FK to `sensor(logger_id,logger_sensor_id)` ?

Comment: That was my go-to solution as well. But still, since the logger_id field is redundant as it is implied by the measurement, it's still sub-optimal. And it allows inconsistencies between the logger_id in the data and measurement tables for a single measurement/data entry right?

Answer (score 1):

```
-- Logger LOG exists.
--
logger {LOG}
    PK {LOG}
```

```
-- Sensor number SNS# of logger LOG exists.
--
sensor {LOG, SNS#}
    PK {LOG, SNS#}

FK1 {LOG} REFERENCES logger {LOG}
```

```
-- Measurement batch MEA was
-- received from logger LOG at time TIM.
--
measurement {MEA, LOG, TIM}
         PK {MEA}
         AK {LOG, TIM}
         SK {MEA, LOG}

FK1 {LOG} REFERENCES logger {LOG}
```

```
-- Value VAL was received from sensor number SNS#
-- of logger LOG in measurement batch MEA.
--
sensor_meas {MEA, LOG, SNS#, VAL}
         PK {MEA, LOG, SNS#}

FK1 {LOG, SNS#} REFERENCES sensor {LOG, SNS#}

FK2 {MEA, LOG}  REFERENCES measurement {MEA, LOG}
```

Note:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
AK = Alternate Key   (Unique)
SK = Proper Superkey (Unique)
FK = Foreign Key
```

```
Using suffix # to save on screen space.
OK for SQL Server and Oracle, for others use _NO.
For example, rename SNS# to SNS_NO.
```

Answer (score 0):

- Why would `measurement` have a bigint that references a regular int in `logger`? one or the other (likely just an int)
- If sensor_measurement_data is 1:1 with measurement, just add the data on `measurement`. Why is this two separate tables?

Suggested schema,

```
CREATE TABLE logger (
    logger_id  serial PRIMARY KEY
);


CREATE TABLE sensor (
    sensor_id    serial   PRIMARY KEY
    logger_id    int      REFERENCES logger,
);

CREATE TABLE measurement (
    measurement_id  serial  PRIMARY KEY,
    sensor_id       int     REFERENCES sensor,
    data            -- whatever
);
```

Comment: There is no bigint reference to the logger id? It's just the PK of the measurement. The relationship between measurement and data is 1 to many, so including it is not an option.

Comment: What does it mean to have one measurement and lots of data? If you have lots of data on each measurement, can those not just be columns on the measurement?

Comment: A logger has 1..n sensors. Each measurement contains data from one logger at a certain time, so 1..n sensors per measurement. Where n may be 1 to 10. I don't feel like putting 20 extra columns (1 for data, 1 for reference to sensor) is the solution here.

Comment: Also, the other way around (adding the measurment columns to the data) is not ideal - the measurement table contains multiple date/time columns, checksums and signatures which I don't want to store redudantly. I think the schema is 'correct' or even optimal as I outlined above.. the only think I'd like is to ensure is the integrity of the references to the sensors in the data table.